# What's the difference between buying a "PC game" and a "PC code"?

Tags: pc, ubisoft-connect

I have been playing Xbox games on Windows 10 and I want to buy Far Cry 3 to play on my PC. On Amazon I see two different things: one is Far Cry 3 for PC only which is the one I should buy but then there is also another much cheaper which says Far Cry 3 (PC Code). What is Far Cry 3 (PC Code)? Is it full game or a key to download the game from somewhere or something else?

Comment: Yes the PC Code would usually be the game key you can put into steam.

Comment: I believe z' is correct, but do make sure it's a code for Steam and not for Uplay, otherwise you need new software too.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf: How you can know uPlay is connected to requiring new software? Maybe he just doesn't have steam but uPlay isntead. In that case your advise is "make sure that you will need additional software"...  as he didn't mention what portal, if any, he is using.

Comment: @Zaibis, i guess i wasnt too clear. I meant new software as in uPlay, not something in addition to uPlay

Comment: Please update your question and provide the two Amazon links which confused you. I am 99.658% positive that someone on this website can tell you the precise difference between the two listings.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf maybe OP is already using uPlay, but never installed Steam. Then your assumption that uPlay would be a new software where Steam wouldn't is wrong.

Comment: @Kernald alright geez, no need to attack me. I was simply stating that uPlay might be something to look out for. I assume the OP has steam by default, as it seems to be the common platform, not uPlay.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf In both cases, uPlay will end up being installed, so… Sorry if it sounded aggressive, it wasn't meant to.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Don't worry, in reality we all know no one installs uPlay unless they mistakenly purchase the wrong key, so your original comment was correct.

Comment: How do you "play Xbox games on Windows"? At most you play Xbox games which also have equivalent Windows versions/ports, not the original Xbox games themselves, right? I don't think the current state of emulators is that advanced yet.

Comment: @XiangJi I play Xbox labelled games in windows store like overkill 3 , fifa 15 UT etc

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth Yeah so that's games available on both platforms. Not really Xbox games themselves then. I understand.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

"PC Code" or "Key" refers to a product key that can be used to activate a game on a download platform, such as Steam (the big one), Origin (EA), uPlay (Ubisoft) or GOG. Once activated, you can download the game through this platform. Typically, this platform will also keep your game up to date.

If a product is sold as "PC Code", you will (probably) not get a physical disc copy. The article description should note which platform the key can be used on. Note that Far Cry 3 always requires uPlay, even when buying a steam key (launching the game will launch the game through uPlay).

---

#### A word of warning

Be *very* careful who you buy product keys from. Not all key sellers are legitimate, and using a fraudulent key (such as one bought with a stolen credit card) may result in the platform owner removing the game from your library. Take a look at this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/2yjipo/keyresellers_and_what_they_mean_for_you_xpost/) for more information about key resellers.

Comment: +1, especially about the last warning. Storytime: I had people trying to sell me Sims 4 keys for 3$ in my GTA V modding days. They probably used stolen credit cards and here are two things: 1) Some confessed that they do use stolen CCs (did report them). 2) Some friends of mine who got from them got the games removed or accounts banned. People wanting more details can ping me in chat.

Comment: I installed steam but when I go to steam and search far cry 3, I first need to pay and then I can download it.. So shouldnt I just pay in steam and download. I still dont get where this PC code is applicable if I will download via steam.

Comment: use menu: Games -> Activate a Product on Steam (https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5414-TFBN-1352) and then insert your key. You have to do it thru app, not website.

Comment: @Jan'splite'Kondelík I got pinged for your comment since I wrote this answer. To notify someone other than the post owner, you need use `@username`

Comment: Pinging @BhaskarVashishth to look at Jan's comment

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth When you buy a game directly through Steam you are specifically buying it from the Steam store, which is its own separate store. Amazon could sell you the same game at a different price, offer its own special deals on the game, sell it to you as part of a bundle or even give it away for free. But they can't directly unlock it for you on Steam because they don't have access to your Steam account. That's why they give you a code instead.

Comment: @MrLemon Just a SE usage note, the previous commenter always gets a ping as well. You don't need `@` pings to ping the person who just commented. Also, sorry Bauce. :p

Answer (score 18):

Speaking of Far Cry 3 specifically:

**PC Standard** is the physical disc. You will still need Uplay to activate it.

**PC Download Standard** and **PC Download Deluxe** are codes to be redeemed on Uplay.

**PC Download Standard - Steam DRM** and **PC Download Deluxe - Steam DRM** are codes to be redeemed on Steam, but this is just a semi-redeem, Steam will launch Uplay when you launch FC3, and it will ask you to redeem the code again the first time you launch. After that it launches Uplay (updates it) and then the game automatically.

So in conclusion: **You always need Uplay.**

Comment: Thanks for the info. I thought we were stuck with Steam. If there's any chance to avoid Steam then it should be done.

Comment: @Dunk That depends on your perspective, I think. Most people would rather avoid uPlay or the other publisher-specific networks if they could just use Steam.

Comment: @dunk I am fairly sure that I'm not the only one who thinks the fragmentation of their games library across a dozen different accounts, DRM platforms and networks is not an optimal solution. To put it more strongly: I've actually bought games a second time just so my 300 game library is more centralized, though usually that's to replace an older boxed copy with a digitally distributed copy.

Comment: I think that this answer needs to point out the specitivity of this to being for Far Cry. Others in the future may come looking at this for general information on PC codes and may think Uplay is required for any online-purchased code.

Comment: @agweber Fair point.

Comment: Steam is great, until you have any issues. Then their customer service is the absolute worst. There's lists of things they will not even respond to, even if it is absolutely their fault. I had a single issue with them, I looked past it. Then I had a second and tried working through customer service. Then a couple weeks after that, yet another. I will no longer buy any games that require Steam. They are nothing but thieves, IMO.

Comment: @Dunk Welcome to the world of online purchasing. If you don't like it, wait till you get the demo CD's with PC Gamer Magazine.